# Unable to start the stopwatch timer

Tags: javascript, dojo, settimeout

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014480/set-value-text-of-a-span-element-using-dojo).

I am using `setTimeout()` to increment the stopwatch milliseconds and have following code to display it.

```
domAttr.set("milliseconds", "innerHTML", milliseconds);
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'set'
```

even though I have included the required module `dojo/dom-attr`.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7b9S/10/) so far.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/dom-attr"], function(Button, dom, domAttr)`. You're requiring 4 modules but only passing 3 to your function. Change to `function(Button, dom, domReady, domAttr)`

Comment: Yes, I am aware about that. I believe `dojo/domReady!` is a plugin and doesnt need to be passed into the function.

Comment: It does, even plugins have a return object (look at the `dojo/text` plugin for example). Besides that, `dojo/domReady!` is actually a special one because it can be used as a normal module. But the conclusion is: every module/plugin has a result, useful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your modules and your callbacks are not matching. You have the following modules + callback:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/dom-attr"], function(Button, dom, domAttr) {
    // code
});
```

Your function parameters will in fact contain the result of the module corresponding to it (in the same order), so that means:

- `dijit/form/Button` = `Button` (ok)
- `dojo/dom` = `dom` (ok)
- `dojo/domReady!` = `domAttr` (**not ok**)

Every module has a result, even the ones that might not seem to have a useful result (like `dojo/domReady!`). So because you're calling the `set()` function on `dojo/domReady!` (which has no such function) your code fails.

The solution is to move the `dojo/domReady!` module to the end of the list, for example:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-attr",  "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom, domAttr) {
    // code
});
```

I recently wrote a [complete guide/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012256/how-to-know-which-dojo-amd-require-clause-with-no-name) about how the `require()` stuff works which might be interesting to read if you don't understand it. I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/P7b9S/11/).